# Toggle between clicks

Tags: jquery

Learning JQuery...

I've the following HTML markup from "learning JQuery" book:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div#f-author').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('boldFont')) {
      $(this).replaceWith('<div id="f-author">' + $(this).text() + '</div>');
    } else {
      $(this).wrapInner('<b></b>').addClass('boldFont');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
      <h1 id="f-title">Flatland: A Romance of Many Dimensions</h1>
      <div id="f-author">by Edwin A. Abbott</div>
      <h2>Part 1, Section 3</h2>
      <h3 id="f-subtitle">Concerning the Inhabitants of Flatland</h3>
      <div id="excerpt">an excerpt</div>
</div>
```

So I've to toggle the `<div id="f-author">by Edwin A. Abbott</div>` between bold and normal, **without using css** **weither by changing style sheet or by css manipulating using jquery**. I manage to toggle one time but no more. Why cant I toggle more than one time? Please don't give me the correct answer for the exercise, but just the reason this does not work.

NOTE: Sorry for all this changes in my question! Will try to do better in the next.

Comment: try `$(document).on("click",'div#f-author',function()`

Comment: try `toggleClass` rather than replacing the element. I suspect that because you are replacing the element you have bound the click event on, the event is not bound to the new element (or as Carsten suggests use a dynamic event handler)

Comment: cant change css file. Must use only jquery

Comment: Thanks @CarstenLøvboAndersen. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

You wanted the reason WHY this happens, so here it is:

You bind an event, in this case a click event to a div with the id f-author. But when you click the second time, you call a method called `replaceWith()`, which does exactly what it says. It replaces the element with a new one. Even if your replaced element is the same (same tag, same id, etc.), jQuery does not recognize this similarity. When calling `replaceWith()` you basically remove all events that were bound to this element. For a nice solution with event delegation, read the comment from  Carsten Løvbo Andersen

Answer (score 0):

Simply check the `font-weight` property in JQuery and accordingly set it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div#f-author').click(function() {
    fontWeight = $(this).css('font-weight')
    if (fontWeight == 'bold') {
      $(this).css({
        "font-weight": "normal"
      });
    } else {
      $(this).css({
        "font-weight": "bold"
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <h1 id="f-title">Flatland: A Romance of Many Dimensions</h1>
  <div id="f-author">by Edwin A. Abbott</div>
  <h2>Part 1, Section 3</h2>
  <h3 id="f-subtitle">Concerning the Inhabitants of Flatland</h3>
  <div id="excerpt">an excerpt</div>
</div>
```